# Executing DB2 Commands from Command Line to Remote Server

Tags: db2

I have two DB2 servers running Workgroup.  For example, Server1 and Server2.

From Server2, at a command prompt I would like to run a SQL command against a known database on Server1.

Can someone explain to me exactly the steps I need to do in order to accomplish this.  And do I simply use DB2ADMIN login for crendentials or do I need to setup some other login?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to catalog the Server1 database on Server2.

You haven't mentioned if the servers are Windows or *nix.

If the servers are *nix, you need to log in with a user that has the db2 executables loaded in it's .profile. (Check the .profile of the db2 instance owner if you are not sure).

If the servers are Windows, then you can log in as anybody that can see the IBM DB2 Program Group, and can open the DB2 Command Window or similar.

From the command line on Server2 you need to catalog Server1 as a TCPIP node. The doc is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0001944.htm). It will probably be something like this:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node server1 remote Server1 server 50000
```

Next you need to catalog the database on the node. The doc is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0001936.htm). It will probably be something like this:

```
db2 catalog database <dbname> at node server1
```

If you need to check the results of the commands, you can use [LIST NODE DIRECTORY](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0001965.htm) or [LIST DATABASE DIRECTORY](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0001961.htm) to see what db2 has cataloged.

Once you have done all that you should be able to connect to the database on Server1 from Server2 by:

```
db2 connect to <dbname> user <username> using <pwd>
```

Once the connection has been made you should be able to query the remote database.

This information will stay in the local db2 catalog unless you explicitly remove it.  (You can verify that by logging out, logging back in and using LIST NODE DIRECTORY or LIST DB DIRECTORY). If you want to remove the entries, you can use the [UNCATALOG DATABASE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0001984.htm) and [UNCATALOG NODE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0001986.htm) commands.

Comment: Please note that there are some commands like LIST APPLICATIONS that require that you attach to the remote instance first.  It's possible to work around most of these using the administrative views in the SYSIBMADM schema, though.

Comment: Thanks -- I was able to get this to work.   Do you know if I need to remove this afer I run my query?   If I leave it, will others be able to use it or would they need to perform the same actions?

Comment: I updated my answer with information about uncataloging the directory entries. If you leave it, others would be able to use it, as long as they knew the database name, user id and password combination to connect.

Comment: @MichaelSharek: I'm newbie of DB2, what the `server1`, `Server1` and `server` seems like? The reference you provided were expired in IBM's support.