# How to connect to a Windows DB2 server from Ubuntu client?

Tags: db2

I want to debug the TCP/IP protocol of DB2 for some reason, and I have installed a DB2 server on Windows, but while connect from Windows local machine, there was no TCP/IP data transferred (via Wireshark,set `tcp.port==50000 && drda` as the filter), so I installed a Ubuntu DB2 and just using its `db2` command to connect the Windows DB2 server. I find the configuration docs from IBM too complicated, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413049/executing-db2-commands-from-command-line-to-remote-server) list a solution, but the info seems too old(reference links removed).

Here is the basic info from my Windows DB2 server(192.168.37.103) after the `SAMPLE` database created:

```
> db2 connect to SAMPLE
  database connection info

 database server         = DB2/NT64 10.5.2
 SQL auth                = TANB
 local database alias    = SAMPLE
```

Then I want to connect to the Windows DB2 server from a Ubuntu client (192.168.37.110) via `db2 connect ...`, how should I configure both the server and the client?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088241/db2-cant-connect-to-the-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413049/executing-db2-commands-from-command-line-to-remote-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided explain how an IBM Data Server Client (db2 client) should be configured.

In your database server you have:

- One or multiple DB2 instances. For example db2adm or db2inst1.
- One or multiple databases per instance.

In your client, you have to map that configuration.

- The server, that could be your local machine, or one or multiple remote servers.
- For a given server, you can have one or multiple instances, and they are called nodes.
- For a given instance (node) you could have multiple databases.

So, you have to catalog a node that point to an instance in the Windows server.
Once you have do that, you catalog databases in that node that correspond to remote database.

```
 db2 catalog tcpip node WinSerIn remote WinSer server 50000
 db2 catalog database Sample at node WinSerIn
```

And then, you just have to connect

```
 db2 connect to Sample
```

Make sure you have the ports opened. For example, you can test if Ubuntu can reach the Windows port by doing

```
 telnet WinSer 50000
```

Where WinSer is the name of the Windows server name or IP address (192.168.37.103).