# How to configure connection to DB2 server, remotley using db2 command line?

Tags: connection, db2, client

I am new to DB2 and need to connect to DB2 server from a remote machine. I installed IBM Data Server Client which contains db2 command line. Now stuck at configuring db2 client to connect to DB2 server. Can anybody tell me how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Please let us know what tried and what error / exception you're getting.

Comment: I dint try anything. For Oracle we make entry to tnsnames.ora and set TNS_ADMIN env variable. I dont have any clue as to what to do !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing DB2 Commands from Command Line to Remote Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413049/executing-db2-commands-from-command-line-to-remote-server)